# Simulating user inputs for R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinytest

I have an R shiny app that allows users to upload a dataset, interactively subset it and then save it to the server. I also have several test files that are structured just like the files expected from the future users. I would like to write an automated testing script that uploads one of the datasets, randomly subsets the table (selecting rows in datatable, clicking action buttons) and then clicks a button to save it to the server. The user input to the app should be partly random and I need the clickstream of the user as an output to compare it to the saved dataset.

Is there a way to do this with shinytest or is that just for predefined clickstreams?

Comment: Have a look at the `RSelenium` package https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/shinytesting.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought of Selenium too but as setting that up is rather tedious (at least for me) I though I'd ask about other options too.